# Assign resolve function from Promise to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, react-redux

There's a snippet of code that I cannot seem to understand. There's a function that is declare empty at first:

```
let dCredentials = (credentials: any) => {}
```

Then this variable is later reasignned in a function later called:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => (dispatchCredentials = resolve))
```

What does the second code do? Does it return anything after someone uses .then in the promise?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Right now, even the 2 lines of code look like they're unrelated due to differently named variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a reference to the `resolve` function to *outside* the promise, then you can resolve it at any point manually with any value you want.

A simplistic example - **it only serves for demonstration purposes**:

```js
//create a variable to use for the resolve function
let outsideResolve;

//make a promise
const p = new Promise((resolve) => outsideResolve = resolve);

//attach callbacks
p
  .then(value => value.toUpperCase())
  .then(value => value + "!")
  .then(value => console.log("Final value:", value));

//add a click listener that will be invoked at any point in time
document.getElementById("click_me").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const input = document.getElementById("fill_me");
  
  //resolve the promise once clicked
  outsideResolve(input.value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fill_me"/>

<button id="click_me">resolve with value</button>
```

You can still use the Promise as normal but you have more control over when and how it's resolved.

This can be helpful if you know *what* operations you want to do but cannot say *when* they need to be applied as the data (and thus resolution) will come later.

In addition, you might have to add more and more `.then` calls indeterminably until some condition causes the promise to resolve. Try entering "hello" -> add to sentence -> enter "world" -> add to sentence -> build sentence

```js
//create a variable to use for the resolve function
let outsideResolve;

//make a promise
let p = new Promise((resolve) => outsideResolve = resolve);

//add a click listener that will be invoked at any point in time
document.getElementById("add_me").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const input = document.getElementById("fill_me");
  
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("fill_me").value;
  
  p = p.then(value => `${value} ${inputValue}`);
  console.log(`"${inputValue}" added.`)
  
  input.value = "";
})

//add a click listener that will be invoked at any point in time
document.getElementById("click_me").addEventListener("click", () => {
  //attach final callbacks
  p
    .then(value => value.toUpperCase())
    .then(value => value + "!")
    .then(value => console.log("Final value:", value));

  //resolve the promise once clicked
  outsideResolve("start resolving");
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fill_me"/>

<button id="add_me">add to sentence</button>
<button id="click_me">build sentence</button>
```

Comment: Neither of those examples should use an `outsideResolve` variable though - the `addEventListener` should simply go inside the `new Promise` executor.

Comment: I think they're great simplified examples. Yes, if this was the whole code, it wouldn't even need promises at all, but for the sake of understanding OP's use-case, it works really well.

Comment: @Bergi it's to demonstrate how this would work in general, not as a "this is exactly when to do it". I struggled to come up with a simple enough demonstration that would benefit from an outside resolution. It's not a very common use case for me, even if I've had to do it. However, when I did, it was with jQuery Deterreds, which [already include the functionality to resolve from outside](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/). And those cases have been rather weird and roundabout for a variety of reasons. Not something I'd call good or clean solutions but it's at least an option.