# Why does this promise resolve to a function (unlock)?

Tags: javascript, promise, mutex

I'm following the example in this article https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/09/10/javascript-concurrency/:

> What we need here is basically a mutex: a way to say that the critical section of reading the collection, updating it, and writing it back cannot be happening simultaneously. Let’s imagine we had such a thing [...]:
>
> ```
> const collectionMutex = new Mutex();
>
> async function set(collection: string, key: string, value: string): {[key: string]: string} {
>   return await collectionMutex.dispatch(async () => {
>     const data = await fetchCollection(collection);
>     data[key] = val;
>     await sendCollection(collection, data);
>     return data;
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> Implementing this mutex requires a bit of promise-trampoline-ing, but it’s still relatively straightforward:
>
> ```
> class Mutex {
>   private mutex = Promise.resolve();
>
>   lock(): PromiseLike<() => void> {
>     let begin: (unlock: () => void) => void = unlock => {};
>
>     this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => {
>       return new Promise(begin);
>     });
>
>     return new Promise(res => {
>       begin = res;
>     });
>   }
>
>   async dispatch(fn: (() => T) | (() => PromiseLike<T>)): Promise<T> {
>     const unlock = await this.lock();
>     try {
>       return await Promise.resolve(fn());
>     } finally {
>       unlock();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In the `dispatch` function of the `Mutex` class, `unlock` is set to `await this.lock()`.

My question is: how and why is `unlock` a function when `lock()` returns a Promise that doesn't resolve to anything; the Promise just sets `begin = res`.

Comment: `await promiseReturningFn()` will wait until the returned promise resolves. It doesn't need to resolve to anything. As for `begin = res` see [Assign resolve function from Promise to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59776151)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it works:

There are two promises involved that are created with `new Promise`. One of them is the promise that `lock` returns. Let's call that promise `P1`. The other one is created later, in the callback passed to `this.mutex.then`. Let's call that promise `P2`.

`res` is a function which, when called, resolves `P1`. But it is not called immediately. Instead, `begin` is made to reference that same function  (`begin = res`) so we can access it later.

When the callback given to `this.mutex.then` gets executed (which is when the most recent lock is released), the main magic happens:

`new Promise(begin)` will **execute** `begin`. It looks strange, as normally you would provide an inline callback function where you would perform the logic that has some asynchronous dependency and then have it call `resolve` -- the argument that this callback function gets. But here `begin` **is** that callback function. You could write the creation of the `P2` promise more verbose, by providing an inline function wrapper to the constructor, like this:

```
new Promise(resolve => begin(resolve));
```

As indicated above, calling `begin` will resolve `P1`. The *argument* passed to `begin` will be the `resolve` function that the promise constructor provides to us so we can resolve that new `P2` promise. This (function) argument thus becomes the resolution value for `P1`, and yes, it is a function. This is what the `await`-ed expression resolves to. `unlock` is thus a `resolve` function for resolving `P2`.